# Add HTML to dynamic elements using angular2

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I need to append dynamic html in angular with in loop.

As I am trying to use in following way, but getting issue

```
<div class="reseipt panel panel-default" *ngFor="let goal of goals">

    <p class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="
     {{'#collapse-'+ goal.Id}}">
     Goal - {{goal.Description}} {{goal.Id}}
   </p>
```

While try to add this code I am getting following issue:

```
Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known property of 'p'. ("ult" *ngFor="let goal of goals">
```

Please suggest how can I resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand your title, which is "Add HTML to dynamic elements".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="reseipt panel panel-default" *ngFor="let goal of goals">
            <p class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" 
    [attr.data-target]="'#collapse-'+ goal.Id">Goal - {{goal.Description}} {{goal.Id}}</p>
```

data-target is not html5 attributes it is used by bootstrap. So Angular giving you error about it. [more detail](http://ghost-imperativedesign.herokuapp.com/angular-2-property-and-attribute-binding-explained-in-depth/)

Comment: Angular cuts data from data-target, that's because it complains about target property

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works fine for me [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + goal.Id".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="reseipt panel panel-default" *ngFor="let goal of goals">

            <p class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" 
[attr.data-target]="'#collapse-'+ goal.Id"> Goal - {{goal.Description}} {{goal.Id}}</p>
```

To tell Angular explicitly to use attribute binding, use instead above code using `attr`